# Deleting nodes makes orphan records

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, files

I have a content type "event" which has an image field.
I tried to deleted the nodes, but I got the repeated errors when deleted the nodes.

> > Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 178 of D:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\includes\entity.inc).

I did not use any hook to delete nodes. I just deleted the nodes from the page "admin/content" by selecting "Delete selected nodes" in the UPDATE OPTIONS.

I checked the node related tables including field tables and I found that they were deleted as expected. When I tried to query the file tables, I found that some records were not deleted and the files in the file directory were not deleted too.

**BEFORE DELETE**

```
mysql> select * from file_usage where id = 41 order by fid;
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--++
| fid | module      | type | id | count |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--++
| 30  | file        | node | 41 | 1     |
| 31  | file        | node | 41 | 1     |
| 32  | file        | node | 41 | 1     |
| 172 | file        | node | 41 | 1     |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--++

mysql> select fid, filename, uri from file_managed where fid in (30,31,32,172);
+-----+------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| fid    | filename                        | uri                                           |
+-----+------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
|    30  | Festival.jpg                    | public://Festival_0.jpg                       |
|    31  | Festival.jpg                    | public://Festival_1.jpg                       |
|    32  | Festival.jpg                    | public://Festival_2.jpg                       |
|    172 | Festival_465x350.jpg            | public://Festival_465x350_0.jpg               |
+-----+------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

**AFTER DELETE**

```
mysql> select count(*) from node where type = 'event';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 0        |
+----------+

mysql> select * from file_usage where id = 41 order by fid;
+--+--+--+--+--+
| fid | module | type | id | count |
+--+--+--+--+--+
| 30 | file | node | 41 | 1 |
| 31 | file | node | 41 | 1 |
| 32 | file | node | 41 | 1 |
+--+--+--+--+--+

mysql> select fid, filename, uri from file_managed where fid in (30,31,32);
+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| fid    | filename         | uri                           |
+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
|    30  | Festival.jpg     | public://Festival_0.jpg       |
|    31  | Festival.jpg     | public://Festival_1.jpg       |
|    32  | Festival.jpg     | public://Festival_2.jpg       |
+-----+------------------------------------+----------------+
```

They became orphan. What could that be why they are not deleted as expected?
Is there any fix for this? 
My Drupal version is 7.15.

Comment: I'm sure the node id 41 in my example is the event nid :)

Comment: I think it would be because of broken links in my site. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally, I got this error yesterday ;-) And after a bit of searching and looking into the documentation, I found that the cause was the functions which loads entities in Drupal and with the name like `something_load`(e.g. `node_load()`). I was using `node_load()` function to load the node and then delete it using [node_delete_multiple](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_delete_multiple/7)().

This error was caused because, I was passing array as an argument to `node_load()`, by something like `user_load(array("...`; which is not the right way to do it.
The argument to `anything_load()` function **must** be a single id. So, you can search for the `_load` functions which uses array as an argument in your code.

Comment: I did not use any hook to delete nodes. I just deleted the nodes from the page "admin/content" by selecting "Delete selected nodes" in the UPDATE OPTIONS.

Comment: @Sithu This is strange! I'm afraid, I've never come across such use-case, so couldn't be of much help. But, if you are sure about the `nid` of the node you're wishing to delete, then you could try to use [node_delete](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_delete/7)() or `node_delete_multiple`(as mentioned in the answer), to delete the node.